# Using Group inside of a function

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g, stored-functions

I am tying to create a function that returns a subtotal based on in ID input to a function. The below returns the correct calculation but it repeats it for every entry that is in the table.

```sql
create or replace FUNCTION CalC_SUBTOTAL
(p_basskID IN BB_BASKETITEM.IDBASKET%TYPE)
RETURN NUMBER
IS
pSUB NUMBER;
BEGIN
   Select Sum(BB_BASKETITEM.PRICE*BB_BASKETITEM.QUANTITY)into pSUB
      From BB_BASKETITEM
      WHERE BB_BASKETITEM.IDBASKET=p_basskID
      GROUP By IDBASKET;
RETURN (pSUB);
END;
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! When you place a question try to add a minimum content: input sample, expected output sample, what did you try, research and where are you stuck. Your question is not clear, what is your expected output?

Comment: Is IDBASKET the primary key of BB_BASKETITEM? If you're grouping by it presumably not. So which table are you using to call this function? You need to provide more information. We only know what you tell us. Please **edit your question** with table structures, sample data and expected output derived from that sample, The SQL you use to call this function would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

I am writing this as a answer because it is too big for a comment... Hope this will help you. I have created this simulation for you: [DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=f88e75c3e71ab21d117a74aedb731f46)
Where I have created a simple table with columns that you use:

```
create table BB_BASKETITEM(IDBASKET number, price number, QUANTITY number );
```

I have then entered some simple data for test:

```
insert into BB_BASKETITEM values (1, 10, 5);
insert into BB_BASKETITEM values (2, 15, 4);
insert into BB_BASKETITEM values (3, 20, 2);
insert into BB_BASKETITEM values (1, 30, 10);
```

I have then created your function:

```
create or replace FUNCTION CalC_SUBTOTAL
(p_basskID IN BB_BASKETITEM.IDBASKET%TYPE)
RETURN NUMBER
IS
pSUB NUMBER;
BEGIN
   Select Sum(BB_BASKETITEM.PRICE*BB_BASKETITEM.QUANTITY)into pSUB
      From BB_BASKETITEM
      WHERE BB_BASKETITEM.IDBASKET=p_basskID
      GROUP By IDBASKET;
RETURN (pSUB);
END;
/
```

And called that function:

```
begin
 dbms_output.put_line(CalC_SUBTOTAL(1));
end;
/
```

And all is working fine.
In my demo you will see that the result is 350 as it should be. What do you expect to be the result ? When do you call this function ? Maybe the problem is in the call ?